# Custom extension for form

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I have a detail page that has two buttons:

```
<apex:form >
               <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn-lg btn-data" value="Vote Up"/>

               <apex:commandButton styleclass="btn-lg btn-data" value="Vote Down"/>
</apex:form>
```

When "Vote Up" is clicked, I want my custom field "Button" to insert a value of "Up" for that field. And the same with "Vote Down" except insert "Down" into "Button".

The detail page uses a link: `<a href="/apex/Custom_Page_Detail?id={!r.id}">` 
to get the record information.

How would I construct an extension that assigns the button values and tie them to the record displayed?

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: you will need to wrap your fields (input/output fields) in an outputPanel which you rerender. Your commandButton should return a pageReference (even a null pageref) to trigger the re-render.